# Manage Expo Push notifications React Native when the app is closed

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-go

My problem is that I had the listener .addNotificationReceivedListener in my App.js to manage the notification just in the moment it arrives with no need to click, but my problem is that the actions to do inside my listener only work when my app is foreground or background but no when is closed.
Just to be clear I use the Expo Go App to prove my app.

In my App.js
useEffect(() => {

```
// Retrieve user session from SecureStore
SecureStore.getItemAsync('').then((value) => setUser(value));

// Register for push notifications
registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

// Add a listener for incoming notifications
notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notifications => {
     //Action to do in my Listener when Notification just arrived
    });
});
```

}, []);